# Tizen mobile splash screen

Tags: xaml, splash-screen, tizen

Would you please let me know how we can set splash screen in Tizen Mobile App? I tried Tizen-manifest. XAML file in splash screen section but when I run the app the visual studio 2017 will close immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you successfully added the image resource on Splash screen section ?

1-> Copy the Image ('png' format) to 'Project.Tizen folder' > shared > res

2-> In Visual studio, Right click over xyz.Tizen Project > shared >res in Solution Explorer. Then Add> Existing item > png Image

3-> tizen-manifest.xml > Advanced Tab > Splash Screen >Add

Then the manifest would look something like:

[image]

One thing in concern now is the AppControl Operation. 
I have not seen any complete Guide on Tizen.NET AppControl Operations  yet. Please check out the existing API reference links related if you can manage some clue:

[Tizen Platform Specific API: Application](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/csapi/namespaceTizen_1_1Applications.html)

[Tizen Platform Specific API: AppControl](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/csapi/classTizen_1_1Applications_1_1AppControl.html)

[Tizen Platform Specific API: AppControlData](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/csapi/classTizen_1_1Applications_1_1AppControlData.html)

[Tizen Platform Specific API: AppControlOperations](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/csapi/classTizen_1_1Applications_1_1AppControlOperations.html)

Otherwise, As workaround you can always try adding additional Xamarin.Forms. Page in the very beginning to generate manual splashScreen Experience.

Comment: I did this procedure for creating splash screen in Tizen but It did not work.

Comment: Not also working on my end, as I mentioned. I guess it could be for AppControl. Now there are two possibilities: #1 As any Guide/Document is not present yet that's why we are missing some steps. #2 Or As being in 'Preview' stage splashScreen feature is not yet implemented. Anyways, Gave a shot to the work-around I mentioned?